# Does it make sense to create a global ng-app scope in an AngularJS application if it's a multi-page app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm an AngularJS noob, as I think this question will clearly demonstrate...

We're refactoring a current app to leverage AngularJS for CRUD etc. Since we're trying to avoid a complete rewrite we're not going to convert it to a single page application. That being the case, does it make sense to define a global ng-app module on the <html> element for the entire app? Is that even allowed? I'm assuming you can nest modules? Most of the examples I'm finding either either too simple to be useful or assume a single page app approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would only advise putting that on the pages that you're using Angular on. It's used to tell Angular to automatically initialize your application module. Furthermore, you can put it at a lower level DOM element if you want to say that only stuff under that DOM element is part of your Angular application.

[Here's a little more about ng-app and bootstrapping in Angular](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).